Maximum correlation matching between 2 sets of points is creating clumps
I am describing here an issue with mapping 2 sets of points that has been bugging me for some time. Any input would be greatly appreciated!
The Task:
I have 2 sets of points living in a multivariate feature space, and I would like to map these 2 sets onto each other by identifying pairs of points that are similar across the sets.
The Approach:
As the "direction" of the feature vectors is more informative than the actual values of the individual features, I defined the similarity between 2 points as the correlation between their feature vectors. From this, a natural (directional) mapping is to assign each point from one set to the point in the other set with which it is most correlated.
The Intuition and the Issue:
I thought that this procedure would give me a mapping that will be roughly 1:1, because I would expect each point to have a clear nearest neighbor in the other set. However, I noticed that this procedure produces clumps/absorbing points in the end set which can gather a very large amount of connections stemming from the start set. After running a few simulations, I noticed that this clumping effect is not an exclusive property of my data but that it arises to some extent with more common distributions.
The Question:
I struggle to develop an intuition as to why this phenomenon emerges; I would also be interested in a more formal demonstration. I feel like their should be a simple statistical explanation to this effect.

An R simulation to illustrate this effect
set.seed(7)

getMaxMatch <- function(mat, margin=c("row", "column")){
  margin <- ifelse(margin=="row", 1, 2)
  return(apply(mat, margin, which.max))
}
printClumping <- function(n, n_tot){
  sprintf("The matching used %s/%s (%s%%) of the available points in the other set.", n, n_tot, round(n/n_tot, 3)*100)
}

n_obs <- 1000
n_feats <- 200

# 2 sets where each feature and each point is iid
x <- matrix(runif(n_obs*n_feats), ncol = n_feats)
y <- matrix(runif(n_obs*n_feats), ncol = n_feats)

# Pairwise correlation between every pairs of points
pw_obsCorr <- cor(t(x), t(y), method = "pearson")

# Maximum correlation mapping in both directions x -> y and x <- y
x_match <- getMaxMatch(pw_obsCorr, "row")
y_match <- getMaxMatch(pw_obsCorr, "column")

printClumping(length(unique(x_match)), n_obs)
# "The matching used 619/1000 (61.9%) of the available points in the other set."
printClumping(length(unique(y_match)), n_obs)
# "The matching used 621/1000 (62.1%) of the available points in the other set."

I could still obverse the ~62% of clumping of the simulation here-above by substituting the uniform distribution with other common distributions (e.g. poisson, normal...), and using Spearman instead of Pearson correlation. Obviously this clumping statistics is affected when one set becomes bigger than the other one, but interestingly is insensitive to the number of features and to the number points in this simulation.

I am describing here an issue that I have encountered dealing with real-world data but presented a simplified example which I believe illustrates the same effect. In my actual use case, I am dealing with gene expression data where each observation represent a cell that itself belongs to some latent subpopulations, and every feature represents noisy gene counts that each follow their own distribution and are dependent on the cell subpopulation.
Finally, the analysis of this matching revealed that despite this unexpected property, the connections that are created still make sense (e.g. it does map cells from the same populations across sets), but it is impractical for downstream applications and produces a very coarse-grain matching. I found a workaround with a weighted bipartite graph matching procedure but would be curious to understand more about the effect described here.

The X and Y matrices in the code contain random numbers and have no relationship whatsoever to one another. There is nothing to suggest any kind of matching between them, much less a 1:1 relationship where each point in X has exactly one "match" in Y. I don't see how the example code relates to your actual problem, you're just looking at nearest correlation neighbor among pairs of totally random data - it shouldn't be a huge surprise that some points wind up on the fringes of the population space and aren't anybody's nearest neighbor.

@Nuclear is correct.  You can appreciate what's going on by sketching a few sets of points on a piece of paper and computing (visually) their nearest neighbors.  If you conceive of this paper as a map of the surface of a two-sphere of unit vectors, then the usual Euclidean distance on the map is an excellent approximation to your correlation metric.

Additionally, the ~62% rates you've found is approximately 1 - (1/e), which is strongly related to the Poisson probability distribution. It's just a consequence of randomly pairing the data, and gives the proportion of samples which will happen to have at least one pair. It seems you are attempting to pair matrices which do not have anything like the matching you expect. You're attempting to pair points that are not paired in any way, and unsurprisingly finding that some points don't have a good pair.

To support @NuclearHoagie's point:  in scaling up the simulation by a factor of 10, I got 63.19% and 63.32% -- both very close to 1 - (1/e).

Hi all, thanks for the pointer with the Poisson distribution. If I understand this correctly, the 1-(1/e) number can be derived by modelling the numbers of closest neighbors for each point in the other set with a Poisson distribution of mean 1. This explanation is actually closing the loop with my intuition that 2 random sets from the same distribution should roughly be mapped in a 1:1 fashion. Guess I was just not expecting the bias towards 0 to be that pronounced.

@NuclearHoagie re your first answer, this simulation is indeed not fully capturing the real-world scenario I am facing because the points are randomly drawn. My actual data are much more structured and the "clumping" I am observing is much more pronounced and sensitive to other factors like the number of features. I think this simulation has shown its limits, but it probably explains partially the effect I am observing.

@majpark Your understanding about the Poisson distribution is correct. In high-dimensional data, there are often relatively few features that actually determine how the points should pair, much of the dataset is random noise. With more irrelevant features you suffer from the curse of dimensionality, where the distance metric becomes uninformative as all points look equally "far away", and you approach the limit of doing random pairing as shown in the simulation. You could perhaps perform feature selection to get the pair-informative features so that the correlation metric isn't using noise.
